# Números vermelhos no Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estava testando a biblioteca Colorama do Python e me ocorreu isso, alguém sabe o porquê? Não consigo rodar de jeito nenhum, aparece esse erro:

```
print (\033[33m'hello')
                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu faço?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estão faltando aspas para as sequências de escape ANSI. Tente o seguinte:

```
print('\033[33m' + 'hello')
```

Comment: muito obrigada!!